# Android studio Lint asks for a value >= 1 even if it's impossible?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a simple text messaging app in Android Studio, but whenever I try to get the contact list from the user's phone by defining the `getContactList()` function, the Lint hovers an error -

> The range value should be greater than one.

Why is that error coming? I have checked from many sources, and tried to write the exact same code that they have written. Here's the useful code:

```java
private void getContactList() {
        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        while(phones.moveToNext()) {
            String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)); //Value should be >= 1
            String phone = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)); //Value should be >= 1

            UserObject mContact = new UserObject(name, phone);
            userList.add(mContact);
            mUserListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

The Lint isn't clear on what should be done, if anyone can help, it will be your kindness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [getColumnIndex()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor#getColumnIndex(java.lang.String)) returns -1 if the column does not exist. The return value of `phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)` and `phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)` are unknown until runtime. If they happen to return -1, `phones.getString(-1)` will throw. Ideally you should check the return value of `getColumnIndex()` before passing it to `getString()`

Comment: Okay, so in short I don't need to modify my code, isn't it? But in runtime, if ```getColumnIndex()``` returns -1, will my app crash or will it only log an error?

Comment: It will crash unless you wrap it in a try catch block. Generally speaking you don't need to modify your code since the database is built by you and you know the columns exist. But you know, things can go wrong even you don't know how it possibly could. You may decide whether you want to provide those extra protection.